# Kotlin onClick events and architecture best practices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, onclick

I have just started my first Kotlin app, and I'm aiming to learn the best practices for that language along the way (and end up with a working app of course :) ). I've come across a problem I find myself struggling with for some time: What should be the flow of an onClick event?

At first, I used the strait forward way of setting the onClick in my fragment like so: `binding.image_profile_picture.setOnClickListener { onChangePhoto() }`.

I went over some of the kotlin training codelabs and changed my code accordingly. One thing I understood is that it is recommended to handle events in the ViewModel and not in the fragment ([codelab#3](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data-data-binding#3)), so now my onClicks are set in the layout xml like so: `android:onClick="@{() -> profileViewModel.onChangePhoto()}"`.

The problem with that is all of my events actually need a context as they start with some kind of dialog (like the image picker). I found [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) recommending to solve this problem using an event wrapper. I read the discussion on it's implementation's [Github page](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9) and decided to give it a shot (also I'm not sure I like this unnecessary ViewModel-Fragment ping-pong). I implemented [aminography's](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9#gistcomment-3245478) `OneTimeEvent` and now my ViewModel looks like this:

```
// One time event for the fragment to listen to
    private val _event = MutableLiveData<OneTimeEvent<EventType<Nothing>>>()
    val event: LiveData<OneTimeEvent<EventType<Nothing>>> = _event

    // Types of supported events
    sealed class EventType<in T>(val func: (T) -> Task<Void>?) {
        class ShowMenuEvent(func: (Context) -> Task<Void>?, val view: View) : EventType<Context>(func)
        class ChangePhotoEvent(func: (Uri) -> Task<Void>?) : EventType<Uri>(func)
        class EditNameEvent(func: (String) -> Task<Void>?) : EventType<String>(func)
        ...
    }


    fun onShowMenu(view: View) {
        _event.value = OneTimeEvent(EventType.ShowMenuEvent(Authentication::signOut, view))
    }

    fun onChangePhoto() {
        _event.value = OneTimeEvent(EventType.ChangePhotoEvent(Authentication::updatePhotoUrl))
    }

    fun onEditName() {
        _event.value = OneTimeEvent(EventType.EditNameEvent(Authentication::updateDisplayName))
    }

    ...
```

and my Fragment's `onCreateView` looks like this:

```
        ...

        // Observe if an event was thrown
        viewModel.event.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner, {
                it.consume { event ->
                    when (event) {
                        is ProfileViewModel.EventType.ShowMenuEvent ->
                            showMenu(event.func, event.view)
                        is ProfileViewModel.EventType.EditEmailEvent ->
                            showEditEmailDialog(event.func)
                        is ProfileViewModel.EventType.ChangePhotoEvent ->
                            showImagePicker(event.func)
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        return binding.root
```

And if we stick to `showImagePicker` as an example, it looks like this:

```
    private fun showImagePicker(func: (Uri) -> Task<Void>?) {
        onPickedFunc = func
        val intent =
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            )
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_PICK_IMAGE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.let { onPickedFunc(it)?.withProgressBar(progress_bar) }
        }
    }
```

The reason I am passing the `Authentication::updatePhotoUrl` function like that instead of just calling it from the Fragment is that I want to stick to the [MVVM guidelines](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide). All the calls to FirebaseAuth API feel like a "Repository-level" to me so I handle them in my `Authentication` class which I don't want my Fragments to interact with directly. But this is becoming funny, as I am ending up storing those functions as members of my Fragment - and that just doesn't feel right. There has to be a neater solution than that. Please help me find it :)

Thanks!
Omer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> also I'm not sure I like this unnecessary ViewModel-Fragment ping-pong

That's a normal reaction that everyone has to it. The benefits are decoupling of View from ViewModel, which makes the View be just a dumb class that handles user input and display results to the user, while the ViewModel is the smart class that handles the logic. This makes the logic easy to unit-test, as you don't need the entire application to be running (which a Fragment would require). Views are quite boiler-place heavy, so it's great to keep the logic in another place, where its easier to read as it isn't surrounded by a ton of view code.

> My events need a context [...]

The events are just signals to the View to perform a specific action. You will not be dealing with Context in the ViewModel, instead, the View can do what it needs with its Context, once it receives the signal to do so.

Events can contain data, but not Android-specific data. If you want to for example pass a Drawable (or any other resource) through an event, you would pass only its resource ID, which the View can resolve into a Drawable using its Context.

E.g. the ViewModel emits a `ChangePhotoEvent`,

The whole flow of a user clicking, and it resulting in a Dialog being shown, would look like this.

The View handles the click, and tells the ViewModel about it:

`android:onClick="@{() -> profileViewModel.onChangePhoto()}"`

The ViewModel now determines what should happen, it can ask Repositories for data, check some conditions, etc. In this case, it just wants to display a photo picker to the user, so it sends an event to the View, with just enough information for it to know what is being asked of it:

The way you had `OneTimeEvent` implemented is worse than it has to be. Let me simplify it for you:

```kotlin
public interface OneShotEvent

abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _events = MutableLiveData<OneShotEvent>()
    val events: LiveData<OneShotEvent> = _events

    fun postEvent(event: OneShotEvent) {
        _events.postValue(event)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MyViewModel: BaseViewModel() {
    
    data class ChangePhotoEvent(val updatePhotoUrl: String) : OneShotEvent

    // for events without parameters, define them as objects
    // object ParameterlessEvent : OneShotEvent

    fun onChangePhoto() {
        postEvent(ChangePhotoEvent(Authentication::updatePhotoUrl))
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.events.observe(this) { event ->
            when (event) {
                is ChangePhotoEvent -> {
                    // display the dialog, here you can use Context to do so
                    showImagePicker(event.updatePhotoUrl)
                }
                // omit 'is' if event is an object
                // ParameterlessEvent -> {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't understand what exactly you were doing with `Authentication::updatePhotoUrl`. In `onActivityResult`, you should call the ViewModel again, with the result you received: `viewModel.onPhotoChanged(data?.data)`, and the ViewModel should call `Authentication.updatePhotoUrl()`. All logic happens in the ViewModel, the View is just a relay of user-events.

If you need to retrieve any data from an API, the ViewModel has to do that, on a background thread, preferably using Coroutines. Then you can pass the data as a param of the Event.

---

You could check out a framework, like [RainbowCake](https://rainbowcake.dev/), which provides base classes and helpers for this kind of stuff. I've been using it for a while, you can see a full project where I'm using it [here](https://github.com/Benjiko99/Android-Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spiraclesoftware/androidsample/ui/transactionlist/TransactionListViewModel.kt).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! `Authentication::updatePhotoUrl` is a function, not a string, and in the `onActivityResult` I just call it with the picked image as parameter (the `withProgressBar` is just an extension I made to `Task<T>` to show the given  progress bar in the duration of the task). If I go with what you suggested I will have a ViewModel with 2 one-lined methods for each event: One setting the `event` LiveData (which I already have) and one just calling `updatePhotoUrl`. That makes this whole class just a hallow pipe that stands in the way - is that the best practice here?

Comment: The ViewModel would be handling the progress updating as well, so it wouldn't be quite as shallow.

It would handle the `Task<T>`, read the progress out of it, and post it as a `LiveData` to the View. It would also handle any exceptions thrown by the Task and make the View display an error to the user.

Comment: The ViewModel is a mediator between the UI and the rest of the application's components. It would for example call repositories to retrieve data. The repository could throw an exception if it cannot reach a API because the user is offline, so the ViewModel would be the one responsible for catching that exception and in turn letting the View know that an error has occurred, etc.

Comment: @OmerLevy if you liked the answer, maybe you could accept it :c

Comment: The task is actually a Firabase task (returned from `FirebaseUser.updateProfile` call in the case), so I don't read it's progress, just pass it back so I can dismiss my indeterministic progress bar on completion. I don't see any logic the ViewModel can have as I want to keep my interaction with the provider separated, and all other process is UI related. Maybe it's just in my specific case that the ViewModel turns out that shallow... So you suggest having this 2 one-lined method for each event in order to keep the amount of information sent to the Fragment to minimum (it can be Void actually)?

Comment: And don't worry, I'll accept the answer after I implement it and see that it feels right :)

Comment: Yeah, the ViewModel can be short.

>"it can be Void actually?"
What do you mean? Events don't need to have parameters nor return anything.

Comment: "it can be Void actually?" - I mean that if I come back to a one line function (`Authentication.updatePhotoUrl(url)`) in the ViewModel, I wouldn't need any parameters to this event. of course events don't need to return anything, but in some cases they do need a parameter (like when the event is to show a popup menu which I want to be attached to the View clicked). I still see some opposing ideas here, like: keep Fragment as lean as possible vs don't send context to ViewModel. Where does a Dialog building "logic" belong (as it needs a context to add an EditText or use res for example)?

Comment: You'd create the dialog within the Fragment, once it receives the event. If you need any additional configuration for how the view should respond to the event, you can use parameters. In your case, to specify a view for the popup menu, you can either send the view's Id, which is just a simple Integer, so it's fine.

You can see how I'm creating a Dialog here: https://git.io/JTqgC

Comment: "I still see some opposing ideas here". You need to understand why we're doing all this work. It is because it gives us benefits that are worth it. Primarily we do it so we can unit test our code, which if done properly lets us verify that the entire application is fully working with the press of a button in a matter of 1-3 seconds, instead of manually clicking through the whole app in hours or days, and with the precision of a computer.

Comment: Next, it can speed up builds, as properly separated layers of an architecture don't have a dependency on each other and thus don't need to be rebuilt whenever a different part of code changes. This separation opens the door for more advanced things, like reusing massive parts of the codebase between different platforms. Since the UI and Business logic are separated, you can have all the logic for your iOS, Android, and Web application shared! So you write it only once because it has no dependency on what UI it is rendered with, it just sends Events to the View.

Answer (score -1):

First, using private backing fields can be very annoying. I would recommend using an `interface` instead:

```kotlin
interface MyViewModel {
    val event: LiveData<OneTimeEvent<EventType<Nothing>>>
}

class MyViewModelImpl: MyViewModel {
    override val event = MutableLiveData<OneTimeEvent<EventType<Nothing>>>()
}
```

Second, if all you need is a context then you can move all the logic to the `ViewModel` and use something like this:

```kotlin
interface FragmentEvent {
    fun invoke(fragment: Fragment)
}

class ShowPickerEvent: FragmentEvent {
    override fun invoke(fragment: Fragment) {
        val intent =
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            )
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_PICK_IMAGE)
    }
}
```

In general, I think your approach to MVVM is correct and all the logic should be handled by the `ViewModel` while the `View` should pass the requests from the user to the `ViewModel` and display UI changes that may occur as a result of these actions (or some other changes in data).

The authentication should indeed be handled at the repository level so that authentication can be performed from several places and more importantly not to couple the authentication provider with the rest of your app logic. If you'll decide to change the authentication provider in the future, it should have as little impact as possible on your application.

Comment: The `context` couples you anyway and the coupling is to a generic fragment, not a specific one (every view in a new application is supposed to be a fragment anyway). The fragment can be replaced with a `context` but I think that `fragment` is generic enough.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't avoid context. It is a better practice to pass it using dependency injection but a viewmodel may use a context. If you want to start a service as a response to a user action, what do you do?
BTW  passing a photo URL is just as "Android specific" as passing a context.

Comment: I'm sorry to be the one to break it to you but ViewModel **is** an Android dependency (`androidx.lifecycleViewModel`), so is `LiveData`.  If you want platform independent implementation, you should reimplement both.

Comment: BTW @Omer Levy if you want clarifications, you are welcome to contact me in private.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SirCodesalot! I totally agree on the decoupling from the provider, this is why I wrapped all reference to it in a separate class. About the `ShowPickerEvent` - I think having a class for each event I have is a bit of an overkill. In addition, where will I get the Fragment reference from? The initial call comes from the xml and I don't think it should know the Fragment. What am I missing?

Comment: @SirCodesalot, Is there a way on stack overflow to contact privately? (sorry for the noob-y question )

Comment: You're right, you'll have to assign the onClick in the fragment itself. It will remove the need for `DataBinding` which I've been using for several years but its errors are often unclear and debugging is hard so I wouldn't go there by default.

Comment: You can't and I forgot that my profile here is so old and without contact information. You can contact me at baruch@nurilov.com.